# Command Cancelled! on running orator migrate command in django

Tags: python, orm

When I'm running the `orator migrate` command then giving `Command Cancelled!`
I have installed orator in Django
Orator: 0.9
Python: 3.9.7
django: 4.0.5

I create created a migration and model that you can see my code and set the connection but when I'm running migrate command then comming `Command Cancelled!`

db connection orator.py

```
from orator import DatabaseManager
import environ
env = environ.Env()
environ.Env.read_env()

config = {
    'mysql': {
        'driver': 'mysql',
        'host': 'localhost',
        'database':  env('DB_DATABASE'),
        'user': env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password': env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'prefix': ''
    }
}

db = DatabaseManager(config)
```

migration file

```
from orator.migrations import Migration


class CreateProductsable(Migration):

    def up(self):
        """
        Run the migrations.
        """
        with self.schema.create('products') as table:
            table.increments('id')
            table.integer('category_id').unsigned()
            table.timestamps()

            table.foreign('category_id').references('id').on('jobs').on_delete('cascade')

    def down(self):
        """
        Revert the migrations.
        """
        self.schema.drop('products')
```

model file

```
from orator import Model


class Product(Model):

    __table__ = 'products'
```

Comment: You're not using the Django ORM? Is this question anything to do with django?

Comment: I'm using orator-orm library for ORM in django [https://orator-orm.com/docs/0.9/installation.html](https://orator-orm.com/docs/0.9/installation.html)

Comment: @IainShelvington have you know abou that. Can you tell me where i'm doing mistake . Thanks

Comment: orator-orm looks like it's not being developed and it doesn't have a big community, I would suggest using the Django ORM instead so that you can get support when you need it